# Install dependency before Ansible runs on GitHub runner

Tags: ansible, github-actions

I'm using https://github.com/dawidd6/action-ansible-playbook in my pipeline and I need to somehow install the dependency before even running Ansible on the Github Runner. And that does not seem to work for some reason. Any idea what this could be?

```
deploy:
    name: Deploy
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build-docker

steps:
- name: Check out the codebase.
  uses: actions/checkout@v2

- name: Uses Python 3.11
  uses: actions/setup-python@v3
  with:
    python-version: '3.11.0-alpha.1'

- name: Install Jmespath Dependency
  run: |
    pip3 install jmespath
    pip3 freeze # just to see what is installed
    sudo apt install -y python3-jmespath

- name: Run playbook
  uses: dawidd6/action-ansible-playbook@v2
  with:
    playbook: provision_vps.yml
    directory: ./ansible
    key: ${{secrets.ANSIBLE_PRIVATE_KEY}}
    vault_password: ${{secrets.ANSIBLE_VAULT_PASS}}
    options: |
      --inventory hosts.inventory
      --verbose
```

Note that the indentation above is not correct here, it is fine in my editor. Everything else works fine, it's just that dependency that will not be installed on my GitHub Runner so the Ansible controller can run using this task:

```
- name: Get all file_sd files from scrape_configs
  set_fact:
    file_sd_files: "{{ prometheus_scrape_configs | json_query('[*][].file_sd_configs[*][].files[]') }}"
```

The error message I get is:

```
fatal: [cache.hugin.chat]: FAILED! => {"msg": "You need to install \"jmespath\" prior to running json_query filter"}
```

Comment: You are installing those in different containers, so it makes sense, yes.

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε I believe the data should still persists since it is in the same job? Outside of jobs it clears out for what I know.

Comment: Think about `uses` as different VMs. What you are doing there is to install jmespath in VM1 and try to use it in VM2

Answer (score 2):

It seems that [ansible is installed in Github Action runners with pipx](https://github.com/actions/runner-images/blob/ed49bcd54387141935c27c3350aafdb5ccfcf747/images/linux/scripts/installers/pipx-packages.sh), so you need to use pipx to add jmespath dependency in ansible-core venv:

```
- name: Install jmespath
    run: |
      sudo pipx inject ansible-core jmespath

- name: Run playbook
  uses: dawidd6/action-ansible-playbook@v2
  with:
    playbook: playbook.yml
    ...
```